# Whats the problem in this function C#

Tags: c#, reference, webbrowser-control

I have written the below function to select a numeric string such as 1,23,000.00
In the WebBrowser I am trapping Double_Click Event and then passing the selected range to the below function.

lets say the initial selection was 000 and my target is to select the whole string as mentioned above.

```
myRange=doc.selection.createRange()
myRange=SelectCSNumbers(myRange)
```

I am returning a Range object from the below function. The issue here is

```
return tmpRange.duplicate();//here it should terminate
count++;
```

when I am returning the final range this method is getting called again
How I dont know, Can anyone pointout my mistake.

```
private mshtml.IHTMLTxtRange SelectCSNumbers(mshtml.IHTMLTxtRange myRange)
        {
            mshtml.IHTMLTxtRange tmpRange = myRange.duplicate();
            string[] strInt = tmpRange.text.Split(',');
            bool result = false;
            result = CheckText(tmpRange, strInt, result);

            if (result && count==0)//
            {

                //Expand the Range with a single Character
                tmpRange.expand("character");

                if (tmpRange.text.Length > myRange.text.Length)
                {
                    if (tmpRange.text.IndexOf(' ') == -1)  //if no space is found that means the selection is not proper 
                    {
                        //Check for ,/.
                        if (tmpRange.text.IndexOf(',') == -1)//if NO Comma is found
                        {
                            if (tmpRange.text.IndexOf('.') == -1)
                            {
                                //EOS
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //. is found

                                SelectCSNumbers(tmpRange.duplicate());
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            SelectCSNumbers(tmpRange.duplicate());
                        }

                    }
                    else if (tmpRange.text.IndexOf(' ') != -1)
                    {
                        tmpRange = myRange.duplicate();
                        tmpRange.moveStart("character", -1);
                        if (tmpRange.text.IndexOf(' ') == -1)  //if no space is found that means the selection is not proper 
                        {
                            //Check for ,/.
                            if (tmpRange.text.IndexOf(',') == -1)//if NO Comma is found
                            {
                                if (tmpRange.text.IndexOf('.') == -1)
                                {
                                    //EOS
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //. is found

                                    SelectCSNumbers(tmpRange.duplicate());
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                SelectCSNumbers(tmpRange.duplicate());
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
                else if (tmpRange.text.Length == myRange.text.Length)
                {
                    tmpRange = myRange.duplicate();
                    tmpRange.moveStart("character", -1);
                    if (tmpRange.text.Length == myRange.text.Length)
                    {
                        //tmpRange = null;
                        return tmpRange.duplicate();//here it should terminate
                        count++;
                    }
                    else if (tmpRange.text.IndexOf(' ') == -1)  //if no space is found that means the selection is not proper 
                    {
                        if (tmpRange.text.IndexOf(',') == -1)//if NO Comma is found
                        {
                            if (tmpRange.text.IndexOf('.') == -1)
                            {
                                //EOS
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //. is found

                                SelectCSNumbers(tmpRange.duplicate());
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            SelectCSNumbers(tmpRange.duplicate());
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            return tmpRange.duplicate();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't help immediately, but addresses a bigger problem

This code needs to be refactored.  It will cause problems for you down the line.  You have copy-pasted code that will be a pain to take care of.  And also, it makes it harder for others to help.

Here is a suggestion for a refactoring (Not Tested)

```
    private mshtml.IHTMLTxtRange SelectCSNumbers(mshtml.IHTMLTxtRange myRange)
    {
        mshtml.IHTMLTxtRange tmpRange = myRange.duplicate();
        string[] strInt = tmpRange.text.Split(',');
        bool result = false;
        result = CheckText(tmpRange, strInt, result);

        if (result && count==0)//
        {

            //Expand the Range with a single Character
            tmpRange.expand("character");

            if (tmpRange.text.Length > myRange.text.Length)
            {
                if (tmpRange.text.IndexOf(' ') == -1)  //if no space is found that means the selection is not proper 
                {

                    SomeOtherFunction(tmpRange);
                }
                else if (tmpRange.text.IndexOf(' ') != -1)
                {
                    tmpRange = myRange.duplicate();
                    tmpRange.moveStart("character", -1);

                    SomeOtherFunction(tmpRange);

                }

            }
            else if (tmpRange.text.Length == myRange.text.Length)
            {
                tmpRange = myRange.duplicate();
                tmpRange.moveStart("character", -1);
                if (tmpRange.text.Length == myRange.text.Length)
                {
                    //tmpRange = null;
                    return tmpRange.duplicate();//here it should terminate
                    count++;
                }
                else if (tmpRange.text.IndexOf(' ') == -1)  //if no space is found that means the selection is not proper 
                {
                    SomeOtherFunction(tmpRange);
                }

            }
        }
        return tmpRange.duplicate();
    }


    private void SomeOtherFunction(mshtml.IHTMLTxtRange tmpRange)
    {
        if (tmpRange.text.IndexOf(',') == -1)//if NO Comma is found
        {
            if (tmpRange.text.IndexOf('.') == -1)
            {
                //EOS
            }
            else
            {
                //. is found

                SelectCSNumbers(tmpRange.duplicate());
            }
        }
        else
        {

            SelectCSNumbers(tmpRange.duplicate());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Random guess:

```
if (tmpRange.text.Length == myRange.text.Length)
{
    count++;
    return tmpRange.duplicate();
}
```

If you put `count++` after the `return` statement, it will never be executed.